# Referencing DOM Elements in dash callback

Tags: callback, plotly-dash

I would like to reference the value of an element in a dash callback. I don' want that element to be a trigger to my callback so I can't call it an input (otherwise it will trigger the input).

Is this possible or is the callback nature one in which the context is only in the inputs and outputs.

If this is not possible, is there a way to capture the callback trigger (yes ctx.triggered_id) and then return a no-op (i.e. don't do anything).

Worst case I have to rebuild 4 plots and a table for nothing if this field changes. It is essentially a category field. If the item (element of category) is empty when we trigger the callback (with another filter) I want to populate the item list with all items from the category - hence need to know current category.

If I change the category I have a different callback that sets the item selection values - that is all good.

I tried adding category as an input and returning nothing if that is the trigger (unsurprisingly this upsets things).

I could just let it run but it is spurious work for the system and not fast.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case...anyone else is as "limited" as I.

dash.State is what I needed. It passes arguments without using them as triggers. So callback has Inputs, Outputs and States.